# Raspberry Pi Zero W not interacting with GSM HAT

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, serial, uart, hat

I have Raspberry Pi Zero W and [this](https://www.waveshare.com/gsm-gprs-gnss-hat.htm) hat.
[image: My Setup]

##### I did the following things:

- disabled login shell through serial in rasp-config
- enabled serial port hardware in rasp-config
- removed `console=serial0` in /boot/cmdline.txt
- added lines to `/boot/config.txt`:

  - `enable_uart=1`
  - `dtoverlay=pi-miniuart-bt`

Then I restart the RPI.

##### Problem...

But when I do `sudo minicom -D /dev/serial0` (serial1, ttyS0, and ttyAMA0 doesnt work either), it says its offline...

Am I missing something?

##### Here are all the files that might be interesting:

###### cmdline.txt:

```
console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=207a6d11-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

###### config.txt:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

#Enable UART
dtoverlay=pi-miniuart-bt
enable_uart=1

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Comment: Why did you do all these contradictory things?  What do the instructions for the HAT say? Did you follow them? Do not post links, if you really need to include files contents in your question.

Comment: I did those things because I found them [project i found online](https://www.instructables.com/IOT-BIT-GSM-V15-Hat-for-the-Raspberry-Pi/). The [User Manual](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/4/4a/GSM_GPRS_GNSS_HAT_User_Manual_EN.pdf) states that I just have to set the jumper correctly, plug it into the gpio pins, and change the setting I did with `rasp-config`. I reverted the extra changes I did and tried again, but it still didn't work... How would I go about diagnosing the problem?